# How to interpolate time series based on time gap between non null values in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, time-series, interpolation

I would like to interpolate time series data. Thereby, the challenge is to interpolate only if the time interval between the existing values is not greater than a specified limit.

Input data

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "60g").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([{'timestamp': 1642205833225, 'value': 58.00},
                            {'timestamp': 1642205888654, 'value': float('nan')},
                            {'timestamp': 1642205899657, 'value': float('nan')},
                            {'timestamp': 1642205892970, 'value': 55.00},
                            {'timestamp': 1642206338180, 'value': float('nan')},
                            {'timestamp': 1642206353652, 'value': 56.45},
                            {'timestamp': 1642206853451, 'value': float('nan')},
                            {'timestamp': 1642207353652, 'value': 80.45}
                            ])
```

```
df.show()

+-------------+-----+
|    timestamp|value|
+-------------+-----+
|1642205833225| 58.0|
|1642205888654|  NaN|
|1642205899654|  NaN|
|1642205892970| 55.0|
|1642206338180|  NaN|
|1642206353652|56.45|
|1642206853451|  NaN|
|1642207353652|80.45|
+-------------+-----+
```

First I want to calculate the time gap to the next existing value
(`next_value - current_value`).

```
+-------------+-----+---------------+
|    timestamp|value|timegap_to_next|
+-------------+-----+---------------+
|1642205833225| 58.0|          59745|
|1642205888654|  NaN|            NaN|
|1642205899657|  NaN|            NaN|
|1642205892970| 55.0|         460682|
|1642206338180|  NaN|            NaN|
|1642206353652|56.45|        1030300|
|1642206853451|  NaN|            NaN|
|1642207383952|80.45|            NaN|
+-------------+-----+---------------+
```

Based on the calculated `Timegap` the interpolation should be done. In this case the threshold is `500000`.

Final Output:

```
+-------------+-----+---------------+
|    timestamp|value|timegap_to_next|
+-------------+-----+---------------+
|1642205833225| 58.0|          59745|
|1642205888654| 57.0|            NaN|
|1642205899657| 56.0|            NaN|
|1642205892970| 55.0|         460682|
|1642206338180|55.75|            NaN|
|1642206353652|56.45|        1030300|
|1642206853451|  NaN|            NaN|
|1642207383952|80.45|            NaN|
+-------------+-----+---------------+
```

Can anybody help me with this special case? That would be very nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having this input dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1642205833225, 58.00), (1642205888654, float('nan')),
    (1642205899657, float('nan')), (1642205899970, 55.00),
    (1642206338180, float('nan')), (1642206353652, 56.45),
    (1642206853451, float('nan')), (1642207353652, 80.45)
], ["timestamp", "value"])

# replace NaN value by Nulls
df = df.replace(float("nan"), None, ["value"])
```

You can use some window functions (`last`, `first`) to get next and previous non null values for each row and calculate the time gap like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w1 = Window.orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(1, Window.unboundedFollowing)
w2 = Window.orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

df = (
    df.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("timestamp")))
    .withColumn("next_val", F.first("value", ignorenulls=True).over(w1))
    .withColumn("next_rn", F.first(F.when(F.col("value").isNotNull(), F.col("rn")), ignorenulls=True).over(w1))
    .withColumn("prev_val", F.last("value", ignorenulls=True).over(w2))
    .withColumn("prev_rn", F.last(F.when(F.col("value").isNotNull(), F.col("rn")), ignorenulls=True).over(w2))
    .withColumn("timegap_to_next", F.when(F.col("value").isNotNull(), F.min(F.when(F.col("value").isNotNull(), F.col("timestamp"))).over(w1) - F.col("timestamp")))
)
```

Now, you can do the linear interpolation of column `value` depending on your threshold using `when` expression:

```
w3 = Window.orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

df = df.withColumn(
    "value",
    F.coalesce(
        "value",
        F.when(
            F.last("timegap_to_next", ignorenulls=True).over(w3) < 500000,
            (F.col("prev_val") + 
            ((F.col("next_val") - F.col("prev_val"))/ 
            (F.col("next_timestamp") - F.col("prev_next_timestamp"))
            * (F.col("timestamp") - F.col("prev_next_timestamp")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
).select("timestamp", "value", "timegap_to_next")

df.show()

#+-------------+------+---------------+
#|    timestamp| value|timegap_to_next|
#+-------------+------+---------------+
#|1642205833225|  58.0|          66745|
#|1642205888654|  56.0|           null|
#|1642205899657|  57.0|           null|
#|1642205899970|  55.0|         453682|
#|1642206338180|55.725|           null|
#|1642206353652| 56.45|        1000000|
#|1642206853451|  null|           null|
#|1642207353652| 80.45|           null|
#+-------------+------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the provided approach! Why are you using the row number instead of the timestamp ? @blackbishop

Comment: @Horseman from the example you gave it seems you want an interpolation using row position so I used row_number. But of course you can also use timestamps instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to this problem, and I have noticed that the last part of the answer above cannot be ran directly as it is, since some columns are not defined. I edited and simplified a bit (I am using window functions only in the first step) in case anyone else find it useful.

Input dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, None),
    (10, 10.00), 
    (20, None),  # 20
    (30, 30.00),
    (40, None),  # 25
    (50, None),  # 20
    (60, 15.00),
    (70, None),  # 20
    (80, 25.00),
    (90, None)
], ["timestamp", "value"])
```

Compute previous/next timestamp and values using window functions:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w1 = Window.orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(1, Window.unboundedFollowing)
w2 = Window.orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

df = (
    df.withColumn("next_val", F.first("value", ignorenulls=True).over(w1))
      .withColumn("prev_val", F.last("value", ignorenulls=True).over(w2))
      .withColumn("next_timestamp", F.first(F.when(F.col("value").isNotNull(), F.col("timestamp")), ignorenulls=True).over(w1))
      .withColumn("prev_timestamp", F.last(F.when(F.col("value").isNotNull(), F.col("timestamp")), ignorenulls=True).over(w2))
)

df.show()

+---------+-----+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|timestamp|value|next_val|prev_val|next_timestamp|prev_timestamp|
+---------+-----+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|        0| null|    10.0|    null|            10|          null|
|       10| 10.0|    30.0|    null|            30|          null|
|       20| null|    30.0|    10.0|            30|            10|
|       30| 30.0|    15.0|    10.0|            60|            10|
|       40| null|    15.0|    30.0|            60|            30|
|       50| null|    15.0|    30.0|            60|            30|
|       60| 15.0|    25.0|    30.0|            80|            30|
|       70| null|    25.0|    15.0|            80|            60|
|       80| 25.0|    null|    15.0|          null|            60|
|       90| null|    null|    25.0|          null|            80|
+---------+-----+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

Make interpolation with conditional on the length of intervals of missing values. In this case the time gap from two consecutive existing values need to be less than 30.

```
df = (df.withColumn("timegap", F.when(F.col("value").isNull(), F.col("next_timestamp")-F.col("prev_timestamp")))
        .withColumn("new_value", 
                   F.when(
                     (F.col("value").isNull()) & (F.col('timegap')<30),
                     F.round(F.col('prev_val') + (F.col('next_val')-F.col('prev_val')) / (F.col('next_timestamp')-F.col('prev_timestamp')) * (F.col('timestamp')-F.col('prev_timestamp')), 2 )
                   ).otherwise(F.col('value'))) 
     )

df.select('timestamp','value', 'timegap', 'new_value').show()

+---------+-----+-------+---------+
|timestamp|value|timegap|new_value|
+---------+-----+-------+---------+
|        0| null|   null|     null|
|       10| 10.0|   null|     10.0|
|       20| null|     20|     20.0|
|       30| 30.0|   null|     30.0|
|       40| null|     30|     null|
|       50| null|     30|     null|
|       60| 15.0|   null|     15.0|
|       70| null|     20|     20.0|
|       80| 25.0|   null|     25.0|
|       90| null|   null|     null|
+---------+-----+-------+---------+
```